# CosmosDB throughput limit of single partition?

Tags: sharding, azure-cosmosdb

In the CosmosDB documentation, Microsoft hints at a throughput limit on a single partition, but does not specify the limit. We *is* the limit?. Here is the relevant documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partition-data

And the relevant quote:

> Behind the scenes, Azure Cosmos DB provisions partitions needed to serve T requests/s. If T is higher than the **maximum throughput per partition** t, then Azure Cosmos DB provisions N = T/t partitions.

Comment: A reasonable question, my guess is that the maximum RU allocation for a CosmosDb collection without a declared partition key, indicates the limit. However this old rule of thumb is now confused by the newer per/minute top-up RU capacity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't explicitly answer your question, but the reason this value is not explicitly mentioned is because it will be changed (increased) as the Azure Cosmos DB team changes hardware, or rolls out hardware upgrades. The intent is to show that there is always a limit per partition (machine), and that partition keys will be distributed across these partitions.

You can discover the current value by saturating the writes for a single partition key at maximum throughput.