# Query on Partition key field spans across multiple partitions in Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have a Cosmos DB Database (with SQL api) with multiple collections and throughput allocated at DB level. One of the collection, I ran a query with where clause having partition key as below:

SELECT * 
FROM c 
WHERE c.partition_key_value = 'bbababab-asas-asas-23we-79ffrreesff'

This results in scanning 16 partitions, with index lookup within only 1 partition. Why would the system scan 16 partitions?
Below is the snapshot of query metrics (where it scans from partition 19 until 38).

I have gone through multiple links including "[Differentiate between partition keys & partition key ranges in Azure Cosmos DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56943309/differentiate-between-partition-keys-partition-key-ranges-in-azure-cosmos-db)", and "[Why is cosmos db creating 5 partitions for a same partition key value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50512379/why-is-cosmos-db-creating-5-partitions-for-a-same-partition-key-value)" but none of them seem to be answering this question. Here the question is not on storage but on retrieval (while querying on partition key only, why system scans multiple partitions?)

**Second Question:** This metrics is obtained from Query editor in Azure Portal. The Query results retrieved are only 100, but the total number of retrieved documents are 1600. Is it that system will extract 1600 documents and will display with 100 each (without going again while rest of the documents until 1600 are fetched)? Is this understanding correct?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: What property in your collection did you specify as the partition key? Did you call it "partition_key_value"?

Comment: no, the property is an id wherein each id has roughly few 1000K records. The name of the property (posted here) was changed due to various reasons...

Comment: My apologies but this makes no sense to me. If you query using the partition Key, by definition you will not encounter a cross partition query. If you are querying by the id when you can/will encounter a cross partition query. You must include the partition key property in your where clause and pass in a value to it.

Comment: Hi Mark, May be I should have explained a little more... This id (or partition_key_value column as is mentioned in the query) is a non-unique value and one value of this id contains multiple records. I have partitioned it based on this id as most of my queries will filter on this id (to fetch records). What I wonder is why Cosmos still looks at multiple partition key ranges when queried on id (which is partition key)

Comment: Hi. I'm still confused. Id is unique per partition key value. If you want to perform an in-partition query you need to pass the partition key as part of the query. By definition, if you are running a query with a single filter predicate that is a single partition key value then the query should only run against that single partition. I feel like I'm missing some key piece of data to understanding why this is happening.